# Which layout should i use to achieve two colums 20% and 80%(Java)?

Tags: java, swing, swt, layout-manager

I'd like to achieve the following:

[image]

The first column 20% of the total width and the second the 80%. And it should be dynamic(ex. when i expand/shrink it should change accordingly like liquid layout in css)

Comment: I'd use a linearlayout with weights. This is a duplicate btw. Search for similar questions here on SO.

Comment: Could you tag your question with the GUI toolkit you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MigLayout is your best friend: http://www.miglayout.com

The code would look like this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 2, fill", "[fill,20%][fill,80%]"));
panel.add(panel1);
panel.add(panel2);
```

Comment: As far as I understand you suggest the the manual solution, are there the drag and drop layouts for GIU Builder?

Comment: If you need a GUI builder NetBeans has one that is able to work with MigLayout: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/registering_miglayout_in_netbeans_ide But writing the code by hand will be probably faster, MigLayout has a very clear syntax that makes GUI builder much less necessary.

Comment: NetBeans doesn't fit, I use eclipse.

Comment: You can try WindowBuilder Pro, it integrates with Eclipse: https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-wbpro?hl=pl-PL

Comment: https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/layoutmanagers/swing/miglayout

Comment: GUI designers usually make less elegant code than when you write it yourself. Also, you have pieces of code in you application pf which you have no idea what it does. To learn, I'd suggest coding it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

For Swing you'd use a gridbag layout.

You have two columns, one row.

The  gridwidth properties will be set so that the first column's  is .2 and the second column is .8 or any set of numbers such that the first column's value is 1/4 the second column's value.

The gridheight for both columns should  be the same.

You can experiment a bit with fill. If you don't mind space in your UI which is not filled with a component, then use none. If you want them to resize nicely but keep the .2 to .8 ratio then try horizontal and see if that keeps the proper ratio automatically.

If it doesn't then try setting weight to .2 for the first column and .8 for the second. Yo're trying to keep that.2 to .8 ratio no matter how big the JPanel is made by the user.

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking about desktop java application (Swing based), you can use GridBagLayout - a standard layout comes with JDK. Although it is somewhat hard to understand. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

The best solution would be making your own layout - it's not that hard at all.

Comment: I would only suggest GridBagLayout to my worst enemy ;) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuLaxbFKAcc

Comment: like I said it's hard to understand.... :) but for this particular case it will work jut fine
the big advantage is the fact that it is included in JDK
If additional dependency is not an issue, then MIG layout will of course work

Comment: If you need GUI builder and want to stay within "standard" Swing use NetBeans

Comment: @Emmanuel Bourg this is very simple by using GridBagLayout, nothing complicated

Comment: The dynamic expand/shrink is very tricky with GridBagLayout, this is were it gets complicated (put aside the horrible syntax).

Answer (score 2):

GridBagLayout is more feared than understood.

I had worked on an application with most screens having a header footer and a left navigation panel. I used Gridbag layout then and only that gave the required behaviour during resize. Had used visualcafe.

Your two column requirement seems to be a good one to start using Gridbag since only a couple of gridbag constraints will be affected.
I suggest to use a tool to build the UI if you have more rows/colums.